# Creating a Local Variable within a for-each fo:table-row

Tags: variables, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, tablerow

I need to make create local variables within a fo:table-body to filter for-each created fo:table-rows.  I cannot insert an fo:block as a child of the table-body.  Is there any other way I make these Variables 'local' besides using a Block and which would be compatible with the fo:table-body's permitted children?
Any help very much appreciated!

I had started by inserting the Variables as children of the xsl:for-each, within which I generate the fo:table-row (see below).  I hoped the variables would remain local within each row but the absence of an fo:block means these variables are being applied globally (at the table level).

I need the variables to be local to each $trajectoryPoint to apply to subsequent for-each filtering.

I also tried using a template but the param's are treated the same way, I guess due to the absence of a Block between table-body and the for-each.

```
<fo:table-body>
    <xsl:for-each select="$trajectoryPoint">
    <xsl:variable name="dist1" select="./distance1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dist2" select="./distance2"/>
        <xsl:table-row>
             <fo:table-cell>
                 <fo:block>
                     <xsl:text>REGULAR ROW INFO</xsl:text>
                 </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    <xsl:for-each select="otherNodeSet[/Distance &gt;= $dist1 and /Distance &lt; $dist2]">
        <xsl:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>SPECIAL ROW INFO</xsl:text>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
```

Comment: Is the value of `$trajectoryPoint` always one element or is it potentially multiple elements? Can you explain what you mean by defining row appearance?

Comment: It is not clear what problem you face. The use of `xsl:variable`s is not restricted by the rules of the XSL-FO document structure. So while there rules as to which `fo` elements (e.g. `fo:table-row`) you can put into a `fo:table-body` there are no restrictions on the use of XSLT variables. Any warnings an editor/IDE might give because of a schema perhaps not being smart enough to allow a mix of XSLT and XSL-FO elements can usually safely be ignored.

Comment: $trajectoryPoint contains many nodes.  For each of these nodes I wish to print a table-row displaying some of its children.

Comment: The $trajectoryPoint contains many nodes.  For each of these nodes I wish to print a table-row displaying some of its children - this is fine and works well.  However, for some of the nodes I wish to print additional information.... The filtering of these special nodes from $trajectoryPoint requires comparing two distance elements (obtained for the $trajectoryPoint node creating a distance range) with another distance value from a completely separate part of the XML which I also search with a for-each loop within the table-row.    I am using 'dist1' and 'dist2' to define the range.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.

Comment: My problem is that the dist1 and dist2 variables are not being created locally and unique within the $trajectoryPoint nodes because to create a local variable, it needs to be within a <block>.  Since <fo:block> is not a permitted child between table-body and table-row my variables are not being contained as local within the first for-each nodes.  Sorry, this is not easy to explain!

Comment: That's what I tried to tell you.

Comment: Updated the code in the text.  Please bear with me as I am new to this.  I am not sure if this reaches MRE standards but I hope it illustrates the issue slightly better?

Comment: The query in the second for-each is the problem. The $dist1 and $dist2 variables are not being stored locally and the results for these "Special" rows include all the otherNodeSet items - not just those where the /Distance falls between $dist1 and $dist2

Comment: `/Distance` is an absolute XPath. As written, the second `xsl:for-each` won't select anything unless the context node has at least one `otherNodeSet` child and your document element is `Distance` and the string value of the entire document is a number between the values of `$dist1` and `$dist2`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$trajectoryPoint">
    <xsl:variable name="dist1" select="$trajectoryPoint/distance1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dist2" select="$trajectoryPoint/distance2"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$trajectoryPoint">
    <xsl:variable name="dist1" select="./distance1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dist2" select="./distance2"/>
```

When `$trajectoryPoint` contains multiple nodes, the `xsl:for-each` processes each of them separately, but each time, you are setting `$dist1` and `$dist2` to all of the `distance1` children and `distance2` children, respectively, of all of the nodes in `$trajectoryPoint`.

Each time that `xsl:for-each` processes an item, it sets the context item (`.` in XPath) to that item. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-for-each) Using `.` instead of `$trajectoryPoint` gets you the `distance1` and `distance2` children of just the context item instead of all of them.

Comment: Hi Tony, sorry when i wrote the simplified code for this post I inserted that mistake!  I have corrected now and also corrected an error in the second for-each - I have made the distance range query a predicate.  Original headache is still applicable, unfortunately.

Comment: `select="distance1"` would work just as well (or badly) as `select="./distance1"` because the relative `distance1` XPath would be relative to the context item (similarly for `distance2`).